# Does Changing Author info in git repo affect other contributors?

Tags: git, github, gitflow

After contributing some weeks I noticed that the author name in my commits were incorrect. Does changing the git history with author info in the commits create any problems for my fellow contributors?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it does affect other contributers. Changing author name will result in a rewrite of the history. This is because the author name is used while calculating the SHA-1 hash for your commit.
For further you can see this page from [github](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)

Regarding  **Bart van Ingen Schenau** comment how to change the username for furture commits you can do the following(thanks for your comment):

**1. Reconfigure the username global:**

```
git config --global user.name "prefered Username"
```

**2. Reconfigure the username per single repository:**

```
git config user.name "prefered username"
```

This will change the user name for future commit and will keep the username for previous commits. This will also **NOT** interfere other contributers.

Comment: Do you know of a way to use the correct author information on future commits only and can you add that to your answer? That would make it a really good answer.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thx for your comment. I edited the answer.

Comment: If I fork the repo and change the history of the fork, does it affect the contributors on main repo?

Comment: You can edit your fork as you like. Nothing will change in the orig repo.